# IFSFile when user PASSWORD *NONE

Tags: file, authentication, passwords, ibm-midrange, ifs

I am facing some troubles while trying to create an IFSFile using IFSFile object from JT400.jar. The problem that I am facing is when the process that calls the JAVA is called by a BATCH user(without login enabled into AS400 machine).

**Exception given**

> Password is *NONE.:XXXXXX com.ibm.as400.access.AS400SecurityException: Password is *NONE.:XXXXXX
>        at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.returnSecurityException(AS400ImplRemote.java:2219)
>        at com.ibm.as400.access.CurrentUser.getUserInfo(CurrentUser.java:79)
>        at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.getPassword(AS400ImplRemote.java:1411)
>        at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.signon(AS400ImplRemote.java:2507)
>        at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.sendSignonRequest(AS400.java:3351)
>        at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.promptSignon(AS400.java:2938)
>        at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.signon(AS400.java:4246)
>        at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.connectService(AS400.java:1336)
>        at com.ibm.as400.access.IFSFile.chooseImpl(IFSFile.java:630)
>        at com.ibm.as400.access.IFSFile.copyTo(IFSFile.java:729)
>        at com.ibm.as400.access.IFSFile.copyTo(IFSFile.java:699)

**Code used:**

```
    AS400 as400 = new AS400("localhost");

    //Obtain the template path
    String templatePath ="/HOME/XXX/auth.txt";

    IFSFile templateAuth = new IFSFile(as400,templatePath); 
    templateAuth.copyTo(fileXML + ".xml");
```

I have check some opened threads but no results obtained. (find below the threads commented)

[JT400 Read File From IFS with user without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529107/jt400-read-file-from-ifs-with-user-without-password)

[Java IFSFile on Iseries testing over PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17409548/java-ifsfile-on-iseries-testing-over-pc)

There is any option to generate an IFSFile when the process is called by a BATCH user(note that when the process is called by a user with login enabled, the process is working as expected)

I need something similar to what is done when a JDBCAppender is created, JDBCAppender object allows setUser(null) and setPassword(null) to enable batch users to write into a table.

Thanks all!

Comment: I dont't think that works. The AS400 object represents a socket connection to IBM i, and it needs to log in to a host server. JDBC and ODBC use different processes. If you need it to work like JDBC, why don't you use JDBC? You could potentially write a stored procedure in RPG to write the file, then call it via JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently had a similar problem when trying to use CommandCall whilst running under a profile with PASSWORD is *NONE. I (eventually) solved it by using the native Java toolbox at /QIBM/ProdData/Java400/jt400ntv.jar (which happens to be a symbolic link). I didn't have to make any code changes:

```
    AS400 as400 = new AS400();
    CommandCall cc = new CommandCall(as400);
    String wrkenvvar_cmd = MessageFormat.format("ADDENVVAR ENVVAR('JAVA_HOME') VALUE(''{0}'') REPLACE(*YES)",path);
    boolean ok = cc.run(wrkenvvar_cmd);
```

I hope that helps.