# Execute CommandCall/ProgramCall by JT400 with Disabled user profile

Tags: java, jdbc, ibm-midrange, jt400, ibm-ifs

Our problem is as follows:

We have to connect to an ISeries with the JT400 and run some commands/Programs. The requirement is: Job is running in the QBatch with **DISABLED** user profile (**because of security reasons**).
We are able to make the JDBC connection, but getting the exception when executing the CommandCall/ProgramCall run() method. Our code is the following:

```
// This way we are able to create the JDBC connection without supplying a username/password
Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2:*local;translate binary=true;prompt=false;naming=sql;libraries=MyLib");

// This way we are trying to connect to the Iseries and to execute CommandCall
AS400 as400 = new AS400(); 
CommandCall commandCall = new CommandCall(as400, "ADDLIBLE LIB(MyCmdLib)");

//Similarly executing ProgramCall as 
ProgramCall programCall = new ProgramCall(as400, "/QSYS.LIB/OBJLIB.LIB/MYPGM.PGM", paramlist);
programCall.run();
```

and the exception is

> com.ibm.as400.access.AS400SecurityException: User ID is
> disabled.:NONACTUSR   at
> com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.returnSecurityException(AS400ImplRemote.java:2889)
> at com.ibm.as400.access.CurrentUser.getUserInfo(CurrentUser.java:87)
> at
> com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.getPassword(AS400ImplRemote.java:1585)
> at
> com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ImplRemote.signon(AS400ImplRemote.java:3188)
> at com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.sendSignonRequest(AS400.java:3465)    at
> com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.promptSignon(AS400.java:3043)  at
> com.ibm.as400.access.AS400.signon(AS400.java:4375)    at
> com.ibm.as400.access.CommandCall.chooseImpl(CommandCall.java:279)     at
> com.ibm.as400.access.CommandCall.run(CommandCall.java:713)

We searched on the internet but couldn´t find anyone with the same problem.

Thank you for reading our question.

Comment: Found a similar question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47513662/ifsfile-when-user-password-none", but no selected answer on that.

Answer (score 4):

You can't connect to the server with a disabled user.

Period.  No exceptions.

It'd be a very insecure server if that was allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a User ID with password but set the Initial menu to *SIGNOFF for security reasons.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=fields-initial-menu

Comment: Hi @jiarong, 
This will be another direction - controlling by the IBMi user profile, but I'm looking for a solution using JT400/Java!